# Failed to run MSBuild.exe

Tags: caffe

I am trying to install CAFFE for Python 3.5 in windows 10. I follow the instructions in https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows, and set With_Ninja=0; I get the following error when executing "scripts\build_win.cmd" in command prompt. (I am running visual studio 15 2017)

```
c:\projects\caffe>scripts\build_win.cmd
The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: Summary:
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 14
INFO: WITH_NINJA                 = 0
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 0
INFO: CUDA_ARCH_NAME             = Auto
INFO: CMAKE_CONFIG               = Release
INFO: USE_NCCL                   = 0
INFO: CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    = 0
INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 2
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON               = 1
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON_LAYER         = 1
INFO: BUILD_MATLAB               = 0
INFO: PYTHON_EXE                 = "python"
INFO: RUN_TESTS                  = 0
INFO: RUN_LINT                   = 0
INFO: RUN_INSTALL                = 0
INFO: ============================================================
The system cannot find the path specified.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (project):
Failed to run MSBuild command:

MSBuild.exe

to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

The system cannot find the file specified

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/projects/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ERROR: Configure failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your version of VS doesn't match with the required version. See:

> I am running visual studio 15 2017

and,

> INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"

Now, you should change your version to VS 15 but as I recall VS 15 won't support "caffe" and/or will be buggy. Therefore, you should get VS 14 (Visual Studio 2015). 
In fact, you don't even need to install the whole thing, install [MSBuild.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159) (a.k.a Build Tools) for 2015 version, add the path of .exe to system variables if it's not done automatically. The path should probably be `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin` and that should be enough to fix the issue.

P.S. Additionally, change

> INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 2

to,

> INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 3

because you are using Python 3.5

P.P.S. If you didn't follow the instructions for GPU support, you're gonna need to go back and do or change

> INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 0

to,

> INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 1

Good luck.